# Discount coupons in left side bar

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

i want to display discount coupons in products page left side bar as new offers ,It is possible or not . how can i implement new offers and how can i display these in left side bar with checkbox selection option.
Please help me if it is possible ,

Thanks

Comment: yes,Possiable.are you want show to shopping cart coupon??

Comment: yes but how can its possible ????

Comment: but how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shakir,can call using xml.Follow below step for this work

Step1: Goto `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/youtemplate/layout/catalog.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
.......
<reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="catalog.product.leftcoupn" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/showcoupon.phtml"/>
        </reference>

 </catalog_product_view>
```

Step then add an file under  `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/youtemplate/template/catalog/product/viewshowcoupon.phtml`
and 
Code of showcoupon.phtml is

```
 <?php
  /** @var $collection Mage_SalesRule_Model_Mysql4_Rule_Collection */
            $collection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
                ->getResourceCollection()->addFieldTOFilter('is_active',1);
            $collection->addWebsitesToResult();
    foreach($collection as $each){
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($each);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo $each->getName().'<br/>';
    echo $each->getCoupon_code().'<br/>';
    echo $each->getFromDate().'<br/>';
    echo $each->getToDate().'<br/>';
    echo $each->getIsActive().'<br/>';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Amit i want a link on it or check box after clicking or selecting its open a page page with all product under this discount.